# Where can I find art that features the Midrash?

Tags: product-recommendation, midrash, art

Many have the custom of keeping photos of tzadikim in their home for inspiration and focus. I have a love for the Midradsh. I'm looking for artist/art that has a generous focus on various midrashim throughout Tanakh in their art pieces. Musical or physical (sculptures, etc.) recommendations welcomed.

Comment: Anything [here](https://judaicailluminations.com/pages/about-us) you like? I haven't taken much of a look around myself, but the artist is Yonah Weinrib, the same artist who illustrates [The Illuminated Torah](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422611128.html).

Comment: Not bad. Not exactly the style I'm into but there were some nice pieces

Comment: My best advice for you would to just take a look in the art and decor sections of popular Judaica websites and see what you can turn up. I'm not sure if there's one person/website out there solely dedicated to Midrashic artwork.

Comment: I wouldn’t consider Marc Chagall as having had “a generous focus on various Midrashim” but IIRC some of his pieces were Midrash inspired, e.g. The Falling Angel.

Comment: I've drawn some scenes from midrashim.